# Sharing Google Play APP link cause Admob ad serving is limited issue?

Tags: admob

Sharing Google Play APP link in social media or forums, cause `Admob ad serving is limited` issue?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing App links on Social media or Forums **can't be the only reason** of limited ad servings.

There can be various reasons of limited ad serving.

1. In my experience, I heard that **newly created AdMob accounts** usually get limited ad serving within few days or after getting some traffic.
2. You suddenly got a **high volume of users/installs**.
3. Showing **too much ad impressions or frequent ads** in a single session.
4. User's are abnormally clicking on ads or too much **accidential clicks**.

There can be many reasons other than mentioned above. This is just based on experience.

But there is **no need to worry** on that. Usually this limit gets removed once AdMob gathers enough confirmation on the quality of app and traffic. It usually takes some weeks or less in some cases.

---

What you should do in this case?

1. Keep building/improving the **QUALITY APPS** which can increase the user engagement organically.
2. Check all your ad implementation and make sure that they **follows the AdMob guidelines**.
3. Keep track of the source of the installs and behavior of the user with the app.
   You should have your own **system which can detect bots or user frauds**.

eg. A user is generating 30 ad impressions within 30 minutes of time. This might be a bot or user spamming. You can also **limit the number of impression/time on AdMob dashboard**.

There can be a lot more scenarios of user spam or ad fraud. You should prevent this as much as you can from your end.

Also for more detailed information about limited ad serving. Please check the official AdMob documentation.
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9493252?hl=en

It's **fine to share links of app** on Social media or Forums to get better visibility. Just **keep track on quality of the traffic** and have at least some internal security **system which can prevent user spams or bots**. Which can generate invalid ad impression or clicks and lead to a limited ad serving.